# Numpy : 3D to 2D

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a matrix of shape `[2000, 140, 190]`. Here, 2000 is the number of 2D slices where each slice is of [140, 190].

I want to convert this 3D matrix into `[7000, 7600]` (Hint : `140*50 = 7000`; `190*40 = 7600`; `50*40 = 2000`). I want to expand the matrix in row major fashion. Any pointers?

Comment: There's plenty of documentation for [`np.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html?highlight=reshape#numpy.reshape), but note that `40*50` is `2000`, not `200`.

Comment: My bad. Typo..!

Comment: There are way too many ways to interpret this. Can you explain where `m3d[i,j,k]` ends up in `m2d`? `m2d[40*j + j%40, j//40 + 50*k]` is one of many options.

Comment: @Eric : Yes m3D is mapped to m2D. I am having chips of 2D images (140X190) and they are total 2000 in number. The original size of the image from where those chips are extracted is (7000X7600) i.e. I extract 50 chips in x-direction and 40 chips in y-directions.

Now, I want to reconstruct full image from this 3D matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a transpose in there too:

```
m_3d = np.random.rand(2000, 140, 190)

# break the 2000 dimension in two. Pick one:
m_4d = m_3d.reshape((50, 40, 140, 190))

# move the dimensions to collapse to be adjacent
# you might need to tweak this - you haven't given enough information to know
# what order you want
m_4d = m_4d.transpose((0, 2, 1, 3))

# collapse adjacent dimensions
m_2d = m_4d.reshape((7000, 7600))
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments you can `np.reshape`

```
m_2d = np.random.rand(7000, 7600)
m_3d = m_2d.reshape([2000, 140, 190])
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is `reshape` as mentioned, if you want row major, then according to the documents you should set the `order` to `F`:

```
m_2d = np.random.rand(7000, 7600)
m_3d = m_2d.reshape([2000, 140, 190],order='F')
```